# Jquery select option using value

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, selecteditem

I have Html drop down. i want to mark "11:00 pm" as selected using jquery in single line how can i do it ?

```
<select name="timing" id="timing" >
      <option value="00:00 am">Midnight</option>
      <option value="11:00 pm">11 pm</option>
      <option value="10:00 pm">10 pm</option>
      <option value="09:00 pm">9 pm</option>
      <option value="08:00 pm">8 pm</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var source = $("#option");
var v="10:00 pm";
source.val(v);
source.change();
```

Comment: This would only work, if there is an element with the id-attribute set to `option`. This is not the case in his example-code.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
$('#timing').val('11:00 pm');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('option[value="11:00 pm"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```